# database query and index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, clustered-index

Given two relations:

```
      Students = (St-Id, Name, Address, CourseNo, Cgpa)
      Courses = (CourseN0, CourseName, Credits)
```

where primary keys are `St-Id` and `CourseNo`. `CourseNo` in Students relation is a foreign key references `Courses` relation.

Assume the following queries are frequent:

Question: What are the courses (CourseNo and CourseName) studied by each student?

```
SELECT Students.Name, Courses.CourseName, Course.CourseNO
FROM Students
INNER JOIN Courses
ON Students.CourseNo=Course.CourseNo;
```

Is that the right query by using join operation?

It's a a primary index because of course number.  Can we consider it as rule to say `courseNo` is a primary index? It's also clustering? What is the difference between clustering and primary index?

Question: What is the Cgpa for each student?

Answer : `Select Cgpa and name from students`

Comment: Clustered index is explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html. It's usually the same as the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with simon at rcl, your design only allows one course per student. Try to put an intersection table between student and courses.

```
Students = (St-Id, Name, Address, Cgpa)
Courses = (CourseN0, CourseName, Credits)
StudentCourse = (St-Id, CourseN0)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the table has a primary key, then the clustered index is the same as the primary key. If it doesn't have a primary key, InnoDB will create a clustered index on its own. The rules it uses to decide how to do this are described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html).
2. Your syntax is not quite right. To select multiple columns from the table, you separate them with comma, not `and`. So it should be:

   ```
   SELECT name, cpga FROM student
   ```

Comment: Question: What is the Cgpa for each student?     is a secondary index because cgpa is not aprimary index and it will frequently access.Right?

Comment: The Cgpa query is just returning columns from every row. There's no need for an index, because you're not trying to match anything.

Comment: in case in future i match Cgpa with registering course for example , with address or with  relation that does not have a primary key .In that case can we use secondary index for the Cgpa ? What the index will be ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of query you're talking about. Why would the Cgpa match up with any other table? Cgpa is Combined Grade Point Average, right? It's a calculated value that wouldn't appear in any other table. But if you did need to match it frequently, there's no reason you couldn't add an index on it. You can add an index on any column you want.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if St-id is the primary key of Students then a student can only have one course. You design looks a bit lacking there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     name
    ,cgpa
FROM
   students
WHERE 
   1=1
```

try this